# LINQ: is there a way to conditionally modify expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to search in my context and child objects for a string. The main objects are 'Property' and 'BayOption' with a property having 1-many BayOptions.

The tricky part is, almost each parameter for both objects has an 'XXXXOverride' bool and a complimentary 'XXXXOverrideValue'. I need to check if the 'Override' bool is true and if so, use the 'OverrideValue', not the standard value. As in:

(LINQ pseudo-code):

```
if (x.NameOverride){
x.NameOverrideValue.Contains(searchString);
}
else{
x.Name == searchString;
}
```

My current LINQ does not account for the overrides and looks like this:

```
 List<Property> stringResults = db.Properties
                .Where(x => x.Address.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.Address.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.Address2.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.City.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.Description.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.GrossLeasableArea.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                    || x.MaxContiguous.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                    || x.MinDivisible.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                    || x.Name.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.SquareFootage.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                    || x.WebsiteURL.Contains(searchString)
                    || x.Zip.Contains(searchString)
                    // tags
                    || x.Tags.Any(f => f.TagName.Contains(searchString))
                    // bayoptions
                    || x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description.Contains(searchString))
                    ).ToList();
```

Scope/FYI: Answering this question will help me figure out another problem I'm having with 'SiteVisibilityFlags'... A flagged Enum where I have to check if it .HasFlag() for this site. (these properties can be shown/hidden depending on what site we determine to show them on, so I have to check the 'SiteVisibilityFlag' AND check if it has an 'override'(bool+override string) and use the override value if the bool is true... One more scope item, this data comes from an CRM/ERP system in a daily one-way sync but can be overridden by salespeople. So, I have to check both places.)

Comment: `((x.NameOverride && x.NameOverrideValue.Contains(searchString)) || (!x.NameOverride && x.Name == searchString))` That should do it.

Comment: Create a computed value on your database that checks the override and returns the appropriate value, then use that computed value in your query.

Comment: Both are good ideas. I'm in code first/MVC so I'm not sure how to create a computed value in this arena. Isn't that more SSMS territory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
|| (x.AddressOverride ? x.AddressOverrideValue.Contains(searchString) : x.Address.Equals(searchString))
|| (x.Address2Override ? x.Address2OverrideValue.Contains(searchString) : x.Address2.Equals(searchString))
//...
```

---

*Disclaimer: Untested free-hand code ahead...*

You might be able to reduce code duplication by making a generic `Expression<Func<>>` that the expression tree can use, maybe something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<string, bool, string, string, bool>> ContainsValue = 
    (originalValue, isOverride, overrideValue, searchString) =>
    isOverride ? overrideValue.Contains(searchString) : originalValue.Equals(searchString);
```

This can be compiled and used in an expression tree so it *should* still evaluate against the data source instead of materializing everything into memory first.  The usage *might* look like this:

```
|| Property.ContainsValue.Compile()(x.Address, x.AddressOverride, x.AddressOverrideValue, searchString)
|| Property.ContainsValue.Compile()(x.Address2, x.Address2Override, x.Address2OverrideValue, searchString)
```

It consolidates the logic a little bit, but doesn't necessarily do much for readability or reduction of code.  So it's a judgement call on your part.

Comment: I like the first option, easy, clean, easy to read. I'm not worried about a little copy/paste... That second option is a lil over my head. That whole anonymous stuff is very shadowy and vague to me... Still trying to get it into my head. I can do simple anonymous functions here and there, but I can't even read what you wrote yet...lol

Comment: @Beau: I'd go for the first open as well :)  If you're interested in the second one at all, I have a bit of a write-up on when I used a much simpler version of it in a previous project: http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/06/fun-with-expression-trees.html

Comment: Thanks David. I have an additional question that I should probably write another post for. I need to do this with child objects as well. I'll post again in a few mins. Title will be something like 'LINQ: child object conditional expression'

Answer (score 0):

Creating a computed property can help

e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
  public string MyProp{get;set;}
 public string SerarchParam{get;set;}
 public bool SearchResult{
           get 
               {
                 return this.MyProp && this.MyPro.Contains(SearchParam);
               }
   }
}
```

To use this class

You need to initialize SearchParam property first before using SearchResult.

Comment: If the LINQ expression is being executed against a data source instead of in-memory objects, this would result in either materializing the *entire possible* set of results before performing the `Where` filtering *or* performing a round-trip to the database for each individual result.  I'm not sure which would happen, or which is worse, but neither are ideal.

Comment: I agree if you are using linq over sql, then computed column on database would be the best support.