# LINQ: modify expression based on child properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have two main objects, 'Property' and 'BayOptions' that have 'override' fields. So,

BayOption.Description(string),

BayOption.DescriptionOverride (bool), and

BayOption.DescriptionOverrideValue(string)

is a good example of how all the fields are setup. (data comes from an internal ERP/CRM system that the salespeople can override the values of. )

I'm writing a search that takes into account these overrides like this: ([Also, see previous article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922227/linq-is-there-a-way-to-conditionally-modify-expression))

```
List<Property> stringResults = db.Properties
                .Where(
                       x => x.Address.Contains(searchString)
                    ...
Works HERE-->   || (x.DescriptionOverride ? x.DescriptionOverrideValue.Contains(searchString) : x.Description.Contains(searchString))
                    ...
                    // bayoptions TODO: flesh these out more...
Need work here-->   || x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description.Contains(searchString))                       
                    ).ToList();
```

What I'm worried about now is how to do the same from 'Works HERE' above to 'Needs work here' above. Basically, the child objects.
I tried something like this but I'm not sure if it works right. Syntactically it's fine... anyway, will this work?:

```
|| x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.DescriptionOverride ? g.DescriptionOverrideValue.Contains(searchString) : g.Description.Contains(searchString))
```

Comment: I spent time manipulating the data manually to test this... apparently it seems to work.. need to test every permutation but I think it does work... Prob is I don't have much data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to check if there is an override and search on that, otherwise search the original description. Something like this should do it:

```
List<Property> stringResults = db.Properties
                .Where(
                       x => x.Address.Contains(searchString)
|| (x.DescriptionOverride && x.DescriptionOverrideValue.Contains(searchString))

|| x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description.Contains(searchString))                       
                    ).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, but not that simple. Child objects with overrides. My above code does seem to work, I just wanted community consensus because I don't have much data to test permutations on.